# stored procedure which return fields unless it's used by code via datatableadapter

Tags: stored-procedures, datatable, is-empty

I have got an issue to retreive stored procedure result ( Table ) into a data table,

when i try to run my procedure from sql server , it's working, same as testing it from a dataset ( I have used a datatableadapter which invoque my stored procedure.

but when i try to get my stored procedure via code, it return an empty datatable.

here is what my query look like (it contain a lot of field so i tried to resume all,

CREATE TABLE #TemporaryTable(Code_Suivi smallint IDENTITY(1,1), DATECREATION date, NOMPROJET varchar(20), ProducedHours decimal(10,1), Accumulation)

insert into #TemporaryTable ( DATECREATION , NOMPROJET , ProducedHours )

SELECT query   -- it will insert into #TemporaryTable what I have selected

to avoid getting an empty I have to not work with insert into... which is impossible for me, have any one encountered this befoure??

Answer (score 0):

I have used another way to get it work, by avoiding datatable adapter, and using sqldatasource to invoque a select query